# Как реализовать прослушивание аудио через vk api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Мне надо реализовать бота, который будет поднимать прослушивания песни в вк. Он входит в аккаунт по api, а далее я не могу найти необходимый мне метод, чтобы отобразилось прослушивание. Использование selenium или requests мне не совсем подойдёт для этого, тк необходимо чтобы показывало, что я вошёл из приложения (VKapp)

Answer (score 1):

> далее я не могу найти необходимый мне метод

Это методы [закрытой секции audio](https://vk.com/dev/audio_api), поэтому вам и не удаётся найти необходимый метод. Конечно, закрытые методы можно найти и использовать токены приложений администрации ВКонтакте, но, предупреждаю, **это нарушает [Правила пользования Сайтом ВКонтакте](https://vk.com/terms)**:

> *6.* Обязанности Пользователя ВКонтакте
> *6.7.* Создаваемые Пользователями приложения API должны использовать **только опубликованные на Сайте методы API**, а также ID, защищенный ключ и сервисный ключ доступа, указанные в настройках данных приложений. Использование других методов API, а также ID, защищенного ключа и сервисного ключа доступа приложений API третьих лиц, **в т.ч. приложения API Администрации Сайта, строго запрещено**. Пользователь обязуется регулярно проверять перечень разрешённых методов и незамедлительно вносить корректировки в функциональность своих приложений API в соответствии с изменениями перечня. За нарушение настоящего пункта Пользователь несет предусмотренную применимым законодательством, настоящими Правилами и иными документами Администрации Сайта ответственность. Администрация Сайта при этом оставляет за собой право на защиту собственных прав и законных интересов.

Comment: Получается через api не получится легально поднять прослушивания?

Comment: @LeonidM да, всё так